# An elementary question on stochastic processes

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

First of all some definitions:

> Let $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ be a family of random variables on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$. We call $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ a stochastic process. Set $\mathbb{R}^T:=\times_{t\in T}\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{B}^T:=\bigotimes_{t\in T}\mathcal{B}$.  Then
>   $$
> \Phi\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^T, (\Phi(\omega))_t:=X_t(\omega)
> $$
>   is a $\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{B}^T$-measurable function and $P_{\Phi}:=P\circ\Phi^{-1}$ is the distribution of the process $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ on $\mathbb{R}^T$.

---

> Let $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ be a stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ and $\Phi$ as above. Then $(\pi_t)_{t\in T}$ is a stochastic process on $(\mathbb{R}^T,\mathcal{B}^T,P_{\Phi})$ which has (because of the definition of $\Phi$) the same distribution on $\mathbb{R}^T$ as $(X_t)_{t\in T}$. It is called canoncial process for $(X_t)_{t\in T}$.

I hope the question is not too silly, but why does $(\pi_t)_{t\in T}$ have the same distribution as $(X_t)_{t\in T}$?

I define
$$
\varphi\colon\mathbb{R}^T\to\mathbb{R}^T, (\varphi(x))_t:=\pi_t(x).
$$

Now it think my question can be reformulated as: Why is
$$
P_{\Phi}=P_{\Phi}\circ\varphi^{-1}?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, even if this is not explained in the question, the functions $\pi_t$ ought to be the canonical projections, then the function $\varphi$ defined in the post is the identity.

Comment: Ah, and then it is: $\varphi\circ\Phi=\Phi$ which means: $P_{\Phi}\circ\varphi^{-1}=(P\circ\Phi^{-1})\circ\varphi^{-1}=P\circ (\Phi^{-1}\circ\varphi^{-1})=P\circ (\varphi\circ\Phi)^{-1}=P\circ\Phi^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, or simply that, $\varphi^{-1}$ being the identity, Anything$\circ\varphi^{-1}=$Anything.